# Getting Exception in flutter json decode FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 5)

Tags: flutter

in JSON decode from HTTP response I get this Exception,

```
I/flutter ( 4840): FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 5)
I/flutter ( 4840):
I/flutter ( 4840):     ^
```

What is this error about?

```
 @override
  Future<List<Coupon>> getCoupon({user,today}) async {
    try {
      final http.Response  response = await http.get(url);
      var items = json.decode(response.body);
      List<Coupon> couponList =[];
      for(var item in items){
        couponList.add(Coupon.fromJson(item));
      }
      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

But there is no problem and the code runs properly

Comment: can you add print( response);

Comment: error disappeared after add return  to this function :|

Comment: Yes it is obvious because function required return value of type Future<List<Coupon>> so you have to return  couponList variable. Did you get your desire results or anything else is still wrong ?

Comment: I got what I wanted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The json that you are trying get can have inappropriate format. Check the format of your json before parsing.